# How to display visible notification from the spreadsheet of responses for the respondent?

Tags: browser, google-apps-script, google-sheets, notifications

when the form sent its confirmation message, control takes the script in the spreadsheet of responses. 
In this case the meaning of a responses is a userID.
The script in the spreadsheet of responses creates a separate folder for each respondent. Than it copies into this folders an editable copy of a master spreadsheet. The spreadsheet accessed and enabled to edit  by a link, no login required. 
The task is to display the link of the spreadsheet copied into a personal folder of the respondent in any type of visible notification in a browser's window, where the form ran. 
The notification in email doesn't work because the email of the respondent not required and not collected by the form. It is a basic rule to save the incognito of respondents. Respondent's personal folder is the playground for communication.
The notification required to display looks like "Click/save this link to open a spreadsheet to enter your data"
Suggestions to display visible notification from the spreadsheet of responses for the respondent will be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK you cannot display custom content using google forms, not once the form has been submited so you have to think of other workflow

Comment: Hi @mTorres, you are correct. As emphasized in the text above the notification has to be generated by the script in the spreadsheet of responses, which becomes active, after the form has been submitted/closed. The actions are completed as listed, it is required to solve the last step, display notification in respondent's browser window.

Comment: Ah, ok I missread your paragraph, sorry. Then you have to look at the [onSumbit event trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) for your responses spreadsheet. There you can code an alert box (but will only be visible if the spreadsheet is opened, of course).